Exporting React-Native app with expo error: Minified React error #130
I have a react native app that i export with expo
npx expo export --platform web
npx serve dist

when i visit the served site i get this error:
Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at nc (entry-ee1b8b491fe6233075a824aed3795d88.js:111:116902)
    at e (entry-ee1b8b491fe6233075a824aed3795d88.js:111:61306)
    at Do (entry-ee1b8b491fe6233075a824aed3795d88.js:111:73372)
    at Oo (entry-ee1b8b491fe6233075a824aed3795d88.js:111:73529)
    at Bi (entry-ee1b8b491fe6233075a824aed3795d88.js:111:121591)
    at Us (entry-ee1b8b491fe6233075a824aed3795d88.js:111:111214)
    at Os (entry-ee1b8b491fe6233075a824aed3795d88.js:111:111142)
    at Ds (entry-ee1b8b491fe6233075a824aed3795d88.js:111:111005)
    at xs (entry-ee1b8b491fe6233075a824aed3795d88.js:111:107423)
    at Ss (entry-ee1b8b491fe6233075a824aed3795d88.js:111:106390)

if i run the app with npx expo start everything works just fine.
If my index.js (landing page) is blank i still get the error. What could cause this problem?
